# Kentico Custom Field Items Based On Selected User

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I have added a new custom field in CMS_UserSettings table. The form control type is Multiple Choice.  The data source for the control is set to a SQL Query.  I would like to be able to populate the items in the control based on the selected user (Administration > Users).  NOT the current user.  Anyone know the syntax for this?  Is it possible?

Here's my sample which pulls in the current users attribute. I need this to be the selected user.

```
SELECT ItemID, dealerNumber + ' - ' + dealerTitle 
FROM cPort_DealerLocation
WHERE culliganGroupID = {%CurrentUser.culliganGroupID#%}
ORDER BY ItemID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access currently edited object through EditedObject macro - `{%EditedObject.FieldName%}`.

Edit:

It seems that a custom macro method is needed to do this for documents. I was able to do this by following code:
1) Create custom macro method (for how to do it see [the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Registering+custom+macro+methods)

```
        MacroMethod method = new MacroMethod("MyEditedDoc", parameters => CMSContext.EditedDocument)
        {
            Type = typeof(TreeNode),
            Comment = "Returns currently edited document.",
            MinimumParameters = 0
        };
        MacroMethods.RegisterMethod(method);
```

2) Then in field editor of a document type you can use `{%MyEditedDoc().DocumentName#%}` and it gets resolved on the Form tab.

Comment: Does this only work with Users?  I'm trying this in a Document Type and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Yup, does not working for document type..any ideas..?

Comment: I've extended the answer on how to do it with documents.

Comment: +1 Brilliant! I used this in some custom SQL query to populate a dropdown where I wanted to make decisions based on fields value on the current form, if one was already set. `{%EditedObject.FieldName%}` worked as you described